# Is it possible to communicate via LINX Communication between threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

See i know there are various methods to communicate between threads but my question is specific for LINX. Please answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=LINX

Comment: i did google but was not able find the exact answer

Comment: At least mention *which* LINX you mean; TLA are U11E. I suspect you are referring to [this one](http://linx.sourceforge.net/linxdoc/doc/). If so, each thread will need their own [endpoint](http://linx.sourceforge.net/linxdoc/doc/html/linx.7.html), as you cannot use the same endpoint simultaneously from different threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

threads of the same process share heap staff, synchronized by **thread lock, Semaphore and condition variable**.

Besides, The communication approach from Interprocess communication(IPC for example, **PIPE/FIFO/MessageQueue/SharedMemory/Signal/Socket**) works for threads communication, too. take FIFO for example(neglect error code checking):

```
char buf[110];
char *FIFO = "/tmp/my_fifo";
mkfifo(FIFO, O_CREAT);
int fd = open(FIFO, O_RDONLY, 0);
int nread = read(fd, buf, 100);
```

Comment: I did this thing.
Thread1() { Opens endpoint} // stored it in global variable
Thread2() { Opens its own endpoint 
                   Sends message to endpoint1} // I am getting error No such file or directory

I am using LINX_SEND System call

Comment: @user2071089 "getting error No such file or directory", you mean using FIFO?  This should be solve by `mkfifo` call to make fifo file first before open it.

Comment: @user2071089 feel free to check the updated answer :)

Comment: thanks for your all help. I want to implement by using LINX_SEND call only. :LINX_SEND. which returned errno as 2 which is No file or directory. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well as per @lulyon, this method can also be implemented. Well for LINX specific, interthread is possible.
LINX_SEND(endpoint, signal, SPID of dest). My bad i was sending dest Endpoint instead of SPID